# Unexpected token ) when calling id()

Tags: javascript, function, oop

I'm in the process of learning OOP, and I believe I'm already well versed at getting errors thrown at me when trying to use a function to retrieve a value. But this time I'm really stuck. I keep getting an "Unexpected token )" when trying to call functions `id()` and `placeCards()` in `appendChilds()`

```
function GUI(player)
{
    for (var i = 0, j = arguments.length; i <= j; i++)
    {
        var display = document.createElement("div");
        id = function()
        {
            idElem = document.createElement("p");
            idElem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(
                                 player.name == "Player" ? "You" : "Casino"));
            return idElem;
        }

        placeCards = function()
        {
            for (var card = 0, totalCards = player.hand.length;
                 card <= totalCards;
                 card++)
                var cardElem = document.createElement("img");
                setAttributes(cardElem,
                {
                    "id" : (player.name == "Player" ? "player" : "casino")
                           + "Card" + card,
                    "class" : "card",
                    "src" : "images/Cards/Back.png",
                    "alt" : "Back of a card",
                    "title" : "Back of a card"
                });

                return cardElem;
            }
            appendChilds(display, {id(), placeCards()});
            table.appendChild(display);
        }
    }

    player = new Player("Player");
    GUI(player);
```

The helper function I've built for appendChilds is as follows:

```
function setAttributes(element, attributes)
{ 
    for (var key in attributes) { 
        element.setAttribute(key, attributes[key]); 
    }
}
```

Any help at all related to the problem at hand or reliable resources for learning OOP would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you forget a `{` in the `for` loop before `setAttributes`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{...}` defines an object literal, which requires key-value pairs. What you have looks more like an array, which is defined with `[...]`.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely this here:

```
appendChilds(display, {id(), placeCards()});
```

I don't know what you are trying to do, but this syntax is definitely not right.

You probably want an object literal, which takes key value pairs.

```
appendChilds(display, {
    id: id(),
    cards: placeCards()
});
```

Though exactly what keys to use depends on what the function expects.

Or perhaps an array?

```
appendChilds(display, [id(), placeCards()]);
```

---

Also that function you say is `appendChilds` is labeled `setAttributes`, and doesn't appear to append any children.  You sure that's right?